# nginx allow only Let's Encrypt on Ports 80+443

Tags: nginx, security, lets-encrypt, certbot

I want to set up an nginx reverse proxy behind a NAT. It will proxy multiple internal servers to the outside world. ALL services will run on a non-standard port (i.e. not on 80 or 443). nginx will also do the HTTPS encryption for the internal servers which use HTTP. For that I want to use Let's Encrypt with certbot. Therefore I need to allow connections on ports 80+433 to nginx.

Is there a way to block any access to these ports apart from when certbot renews the certificates? As stated before, these ports are not used for anything else.

Comment: Use a wrapper script around certbot to open and close those ports in the firewall?

Comment: just to be clear, the nginx has a public ip and the rest is served by sub hosts from lan? if yes thats quite easy, but first tell us more about your Plans @masgo